# How can I set database path

Tags: sqlite, flutter

```
 final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
  join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'login_database.db'),
  onCreate: (db, version) {
    return db.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE dogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER)",
    );
  },
  version: 1,
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin to set different location. For example, you can use external storage (for Android only):

```dart
final extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
join(extDir.path, 'login_database.db')
```